# How to programmatically retrieve GHC package information?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, hackage

More specifically, given an arbritary package name I need to retrieve the same `library-dirs` field that can be obtained with the `ghc-pkg describe` command from inside a running Haskell program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I could come up with by peeking into the `ghc-pkg` source code.

The `getPkgInfos` function returns the package definitions for all installed packages (hopefully including user-installed packages). With this in your hands, you can retrieve the library directories and other package information. See [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Cabal/1.6.0.3/doc/html/Distribution-InstalledPackageInfo.html) for details.

The `GHC_PKGCONF` variable needs to point to the global package config file for systems where it isn't located at the usual place. `ghc-pkg` solves this problem by receiving a command line flag via a wrapper script in Ubuntu, for instance.

```
import qualified Config
import qualified System.Info
import Data.List
import Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo
import GHC.Paths
import System.Directory
import System.Environment
import System.FilePath
import System.IO.Error

getPkgInfos :: IO [InstalledPackageInfo]
getPkgInfos = do
    global_conf <-
        catch (getEnv "GHC_PKGCONF")
              (\err ->  if isDoesNotExistError err
                            then do let dir = takeDirectory $ takeDirectory ghc_pkg
                                        path1 = dir </> "package.conf"
                                        path2 = dir </> ".." </> ".." </> ".."
                                                    </> "inplace-datadir"
                                                    </> "package.conf"
                                    exists1 <- doesFileExist path1
                                    exists2 <- doesFileExist path2
                                    if exists1 then return path1
                                       else if exists2 then return path2
                                       else ioError $ userError "Can't find package.conf"
                            else ioError err)

    let global_conf_dir = global_conf ++ ".d"
    global_conf_dir_exists <- doesDirectoryExist global_conf_dir
    global_confs <-
        if global_conf_dir_exists
            then do files <- getDirectoryContents global_conf_dir
                    return  [ global_conf_dir ++ '/' : file
                            | file <- files
                            , isSuffixOf ".conf" file]
            else return []

    user_conf <-
        try (getAppUserDataDirectory "ghc") >>= either
            (\_ -> return [])
            (\appdir -> do
                let subdir = currentArch ++ '-':currentOS ++ '-':ghcVersion
                    user_conf = appdir </> subdir </> "package.conf"
                user_exists <- doesFileExist user_conf
                return (if user_exists then [user_conf] else []))

    let pkg_dbs = user_conf ++ global_confs ++ [global_conf]
    return.concat =<< mapM ((>>= return.read).readFile) pkg_dbs

currentArch = System.Info.arch
currentOS = System.Info.os
ghcVersion = Config.cProjectVersion
```

I wrote this code myself, but it was largely inspired by ghc-pkg (with some pieces copied verbatim). The original code was licensed under a BSD-style license, I think this can be distributed under the cc-wiki license all Stackoverflow content is under, but I'm not really sure. Anyway, as anything else, I did some initial testing and it seems to work, but use it at your own risk.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically a more comprehensive version of what I wrote -- instead of using only one hard-coded `%GHC_ROOT%/package.conf`, I think you've found all of the ones in regular use.

Comment: I tried to find all the ones that ghc-pkg finds in order to mimic its behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the installed packages database is [`Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/Cabal/Distribution-InstalledPackageInfo.html).

```
import Distribution.InstalledPackageInfo
import Distribution.Package
import Distribution.Text
import GHC.Paths
import System
import System.FilePath
main = do
    name:_ <- getArgs
    packages <- fmap read $ readFile $ joinPath [libdir, "package.conf"]
    let matches = filter ((PackageName name ==) . pkgName . package) packages
    mapM_ (print . libraryDirs) (matches :: [InstalledPackageInfo_ String])
```

This doesn't obey the user's package configuration, but should be a start.

Answer (score 1):

Ask Duncan Coutts on the haskell-cafe@ or cabal mailing lists. (I'm serious. That is a better forum for Cabal questions than stack overflow).

Sometimes you just have to point people at a different forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cabal to configure and build your program/library you can used the autogenerated Paths_* module.

For example, if you have a `foo.cabal` file, cabal will generate a `Paths_foo` module (see its source under `dist/build/autogen`) which you can import. This module exports a function `getLibDir :: IO FilePath` which has the value you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need to retrieve the lib dirs for other installed packages, not my own.